# Disable Hazelcast entry statistics

Tags: java, hazelcast

Is there any way by which we can disable Hazelcast entry statistics? I know we can disable local map statistics, however, I want to disable the entry-level statistics to reduce the memory footprint of each map entry.

Using Hz 3.4.1

Answer (score 0):

yes, you use: http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.4/javadoc/com/hazelcast/config/MapConfig.html#setStatisticsEnabled(boolean)

You have to know map name.

Comment: Is this the same as setting <statistics-enabled> in config xml for map ?

Comment: This is disabling the local map statistics. So map.getLocalMapStats().getOwnedEntryCount() is returning 0. I would want the map entry statistics to be disabled, so that map.getEntryView(key).getCost() returns -1 (as per javadocs).